# How to check action payload before state update?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm learning redux for my first react-redux application. How do I manage to verify payload value before changing my state ? For example the code below:

```
todoExample = {name: 'learn redux', author: 'myself'}
wrongTodoExample = {name: 'learn redux'}

dispatch(addTodos({todo: todoExample})) 
dispatch(addTodos({todo: wrongTodoExample }))
```

With the above code, I add 2 todo items to my state but they don't have the same keys.

Is there a way to check the payload value in order to authorize the first addTodos but not the second one in my reducer?
I've searched on the internet but I couldn't find an answer. I'm sorry if my question is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that suited well my needs and it's TypeScript. Now I have Payload Type wich allow me to define keys that I need in my action.payload without any validation function.

Thanks all for your asnwers.

Comment: Can you share the link to the solution

Comment: Hello sorry for the late answer. I add Typescript to my project and define a typed interface. I then set this interface to my payload so that I don't need to handle the matching with a ternary operator or a side function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use redux middleware to verify things, that is absolutely one of the intended use cases for middleware. Any middleware can inspect and modify any action going through the pipeline before it reaches the reducers, and even prevent an action from continuing on.

```
const verifyPayload = store => next => action => {
  if (isVerifyPayload(action.payload)) {
    return next(action);
  } else {
    return store.dispatch({ type: 'NOT_AUTHORIZED' })
  }
  
}

const store = createStore(
 initialState,
 applyMiddleware(verifyPayload)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear about your description about `same key`, you mean name or author, or other specific keys like code\id.
You can try to validate your todos before dispatch or within the `addTodos`

```
function addTodos(payload) {
  if (!payload.todo.code) return;
  // simply return,
  // otherwise throw an error to indicate that your todos miss a specific key
}
```

Comment: When I said that they don't have the same keys I mean that one todo have an author key and not the other one.
I thought about your way of doing it but it's a bit redondant to verify data like this for each reducer, isn't it ? I thought maybe there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator in your reducer along with some util function to validate your todo. If the todo is valid, then transform your state to include the new todo, if not return the same state (effectively doing nothing).

```
const isValidTodo = (todo) => {
    //Implement your validations. E.g: A valid todo will have a name and an author
    return todo.name && todo.author;
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return isValidTodo(action.payload) ?
      [
        ...state,
        {
          name: action.payload.name,
          author: action.payload.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ] 
   : state
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was my first idea but it doesn't suit my case because I need to show somewhere that the input was wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, if you need to show somewhere that your input was wrong, rather than returning the same state, you could set a different property in the state (something like isToDoInvalid) and use it in your component.